# Display number of sections at the beginning of a chapter

Tags: sectioning, auxiliary-files, hooks

My goal is to display the number of sections the chapter contains, at the beginning of every chapter.

Currently, my idea is to store in the aux file the value of the `section` counter at the end of every chapter, and display it on the second pass. Example of the commands I wrote:

```latex
\newcommand{\store@sect@count}{\write\@auxout{\@backslashchar expandafter\@backslashchar gdef\@backslashchar csname sects@in@chap@\roman{chapter}\@backslashchar endcsname{\arabic{section}}}}
% Writes something like \expandafter\gdef\csname sects@in@chap@i\endcsname{2}

\newcommand{\get@sect@count}{\csname sects@in@chap@\roman{chapter}\endcsname}
```

With this approach, I can use `\get@sect@count` at the begining of every chapter to print the section count. However, it also requires running the `\store@sect@count` command at the end of every chapter, and I haven't found how to do so.

A possibility would be to create a custom environment for this, however this would end up very cumbersome, especially if I apply it to other sectioning levels.

- How can I reliably run a command at the end of every chapter (and other levels of document hierarchy)?
- Is there a better approach to reach my goal, than the one I am currently trying to use?

**Edit**: MWE on Overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/read/hcqjhwbthngs (code below)

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\store@sect@count}{\write\@auxout{\@backslashchar expandafter\@backslashchar gdef\@backslashchar csname sects@in@chap@\roman{chapter}\@backslashchar endcsname{\arabic{section}}}}
\newcommand{\get@sect@count}{\csname sects@in@chap@\roman{chapter}\endcsname}


\newenvironment
{countingchapter}
{\chapter{} Number of sections: \get@sect@count \\}
{\store@sect@count}

\newenvironment
{countingsection}
{\section{}}
{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{countingchapter}
My chapter

\begin{countingsection}
Fisrt section
\end{countingsection}
\begin{countingsection}
Section section
\end{countingsection}
\begin{countingsection}
Third section
\end{countingsection}

\end{countingchapter}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is this possible to post `MWE` of your code for better understanding? Happy New Year 2021

Comment: there is no dedicated command at the end of a chapter, but you could rather easily hook into the begin of the next chapter.  But if you have a table of contents  you could also hook into it, it has all the chapters and section and so counting them should be easy.

Answer (score 5):

You can hook in `\refstepcounter` (with care), so that if it is performed on `chapter` the number of sections will be recorded in the `.aux` file.

Special care for appendices has to be taken and also for the last chapter, so the appropriate record is added when `\appendix` is called and also at end document.

*Caveat*: `\backmatter` would break this.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book} % oneside just to make a smaller picture
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry} % just to make a smaller picture
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\AtBeginDocument
 {
  \NewCommandCopy{\latexrefstepcounter}{\refstepcounter}
  \cs_set_eq:NN \refstepcounter \countsections_refstepcounter:n
 }
\AtEndDocument
 {
  \countsections_count:
 }
\xpretocmd{\appendix}{\countsections_count:}{}{}

\NewDocumentCommand{\sectioncount}{O{\thechapter}}
 {
  \ref*{cs@#1}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \countsections_refstepcounter:n
 {
  \str_if_eq:nnT { #1 } { chapter } { \countsections_count: }
  \latexrefstepcounter{#1}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \countsections_count:
 {
  \iow_now:cx { @auxout }
   {
    \string\newlabel { cs@\thechapter } { {\arabic{section}}{}{}{}{} }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Chapter 1 has \sectioncount[1]~sections.
Chapter 2 has \sectioncount[2]~sections.
Chapter A has \sectioncount[A]~sections.

\chapter{A}

This chapter has \sectioncount~sections.

\section{B}
\section{C}

\chapter{D}

This chapter has \sectioncount~sections.

\section{E}
\section{F}
\section{G}

\appendix

\chapter{H}

This chapter has \sectioncount~sections.

\section{I}
\section{J}

\end{document}
```

You may need to load `xparse` if you're running a LaTeX release prior to 2020-10-01.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As Ulrike mentioned, you can tap into `\chapter` and write the number of sections to the `.aux` with every call to start a new chapter.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\let\oldchapter\chapter% Store \chapter in \oldchapter
\renewcommand{\chapter}{%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{% Write section count to .aux
    \global\noexpand\@namedef{chap\roman{chapter}sectioncount}{\arabic{section}}%
  }%
  \oldchapter% Call original \chapter
}

\newcommand{\thischaptersectioncount}{%
  This chapter contains \@nameuse{chap\roman{chapter}sectioncount} sections.%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\sloppy

\chapter{First chapter}
\thischaptersectioncount% 5
\section{First section}\lipsum[1-10]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[11-20]
\section{Third section}\lipsum[21-30]
\section{Fourth section}\lipsum[31-40]
\section{Final section}\lipsum[41-50]

\chapter{Second chapter}
\thischaptersectioncount% 2
\section{First section}\lipsum[1-10]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[11-20]

\chapter{Third chapter}
\thischaptersectioncount% 4
\section{First section}\lipsum[1-10]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[11-20]
\section{Third section}\lipsum[21-30]
\section{Fourth section}\lipsum[31-40]

\chapter{Final chapter}
\thischaptersectioncount% 1
\section{First section}\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Since you're using the `.aux` as an intermediate storing mechanism, you'll have to compile at least twice (on the first go or with any changes in the number of sections), as the section numbers will only be available on the second compilation.